# How to recive selected value from Spring to Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I send from Spring to Thymeleaf ArrayList, which consists from two BigDemical parameters. This for price filter and I want to do: from 0 to first element from ArrayList, from first element to second and more second
Spring:

```
 modelAndView.addObject("price",filterPrice);
```

Html

```
 <div th:each="filterPrice : ${price}">
                    <input class="priceSelected"  type="checkbox" id="price01" value="1"/> 0 -
                    <span class="filterPriceFirst" th:text="${price[0]}"></span> <br/>

<input class="priceSelected"  type="checkbox" id="price02" value="2"/> 
<span class="filterPriceFirst" th:text="${price[0]}">
-<span class="filterPriceFirst" th:text="${price[1]}"></span> <br/>

<input class="priceSelected"  type="checkbox" id="price02" value="3"/> 
 > <span class="filterPriceFirst" th:text="${price[1]}">
<br/>
                    </div>
```

Code working, but I recive all value twice. But I need to recive all value only one time. Where my misstake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML You are using th:each that loops through the array. Since your array has two elements it does it twice. Removing th:each will fix it. Also element ID should be unique so you should use price03 on the last input.

Your code should look something like this

```
<div>
  <input class="priceSelected"  type="checkbox" id="price01" value="1"/> 0 -
  <span class="filterPriceFirst" th:text="${price[0]}"></span> 
  <br/>

  <input class="priceSelected"  type="checkbox" id="price02" value="2"/> 
  <span class="filterPriceFirst" th:text="${price[0]}">-
  <span class="filterPriceFirst" th:text="${price[1]}"></span> 
  <br/>

  <input class="priceSelected"  type="checkbox" id="price03" value="3"/>  >  
  <span class="filterPriceFirst" th:text="${price[1]}">
  <br/>
</div>
```